# squid compilation and configuration for performance

Tags: performance, proxy, squid

I'm running Squid 3.3.8 on a Cavium MIPS processor, Cavium Linux (Debian).  No caching, strictly forwarding with 'request_header_add' header insertion.  On a 2- or 4- core processor, it's using one entire core for what I consider a light load.

Question is: what are the most critical compilation directives to use with 'configure' and squid.conf settings to maximize performance in a non-caching server?  All traffic is being proxied to a parent proxy service.

Basically, I'm wondering if I've made some bonehead error of omission or commission.  I've tried to turn off anything I don't need, but I seem to have nailed one foot to the floor.

for configure script:

```
    --enable-linux-filter          \
    --enable-poll                  \
    --enable-epoll                 \
    --enable-kqueue                \
    --disable-ident-lookups        \
    --disable-ident                \
    --disable-auth                 \
    --disable-auth-basic           \
    --disable-auth-ntlm            \
    --disable-auth-negotiate       \
    --disable-auth-digest          \
    --disable-ipv6                 \
    --disable-translation          \
    --disable-auto-locale          \
    --disable-snmp                 \
    --without-expat                \
    --without-libxml2              \
    --without-libcap               \
    --disable-linux-tproxy         \
    --disable-external-acl-helpers \
    --disable-wccp                 \
    --disable-wccpv2               \
    --disable-eui                  \
    --disable-htcp                 \
    --disable-loadable-modules     \
    --without-netfilter-conntrack  \
    --enable-disk-io=no            \
    --enable-storeio=no            \
    --enable-removal-policies=no   \
    --enable-follow-x-forwarded-for=no \
    --disable-http-violations      \
```

**squid.conf:**

```
acl localnet src 0.0.0.0/0
cache_peer proxy.myproxy.net parent 8080 0 no-query default
never_direct allow all
request_header_add HEADER1 header1 localnet
request_header_add HEADER2 header2 localnet
cache deny all
http_access allow localnet
http_port 3128 intercept
```